# How to manually release an SKSprite Scene and everything in it

Tags: sprite-kit

Currently having a memory issue and ARC doesn't seem to be working right,so i'm just gonna try MRC and see if it makes any difference. I've tried putting autorelease in any method where i init something, but the game crashes when it reaches that point. What's the right way to release my nodes and do i need a release method when my scene transitions?

Comment: ARC is working correctly, you probably just don't understand the issue you are facing. Switching to MRC based on the assumption that ARC doesn't do the right thing is more likely going to make matters worse, if you aren't familiar with how memory management works in ObjC. You should ask about your central issue first and provide some context rather than doing something else before you haven't given yourself and us a chance to figure out the actual issue.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Not to be to much of a bother, but could you take a look at my other post explaining what's actually causing the problem, i replied to you in it.